# Should you flag "non-answer" answers?

Tags: discussion

I saw this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879747/mvc-multiple-autocomplete-error

Someone posted a question and then about 12 hours later posted an "answer":

> "nobody can help me with this problem?"

I down voted and commented:

> Sometimes it takes a little time to get an answer, but you shouldn't post an answer asking people to help you below your question. You need to be patient.

Is this a case for flagging? Flagging seems a little extreme but this answer clearly serves no value to anyone and is just the user being upset that their question is not being answered as fast as they would like. I assumed down voting was appropriate. There wasn't anything that I could edit.

Is this common? I've never seen a user do this before.

Thanks

Comment: Of course this should be flagged as _"Additional comment on another post"_, or _"I have this problem too"_ answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that is "Not An Answer" and you should flag it as such.

That user hasn't received an answer yet, and they are essentially bumping it like users do in forums.  I'd suggest leaving a comment that states something like:

> Please don't post answers to bump your question since you still haven't received an answer. Please invest some time in the site to gain the rep needed to offer a bounty on your question.  A bounty will help draw attention to your question....

Comment: ah ok thank you, I didn't want to bother the moderators if it wasn't an issue. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @TaiHirabayashi This is the type of stuff that should be flagged. "Not An Answer" flags get funneled into the Low Quality review queue, so those will be reviewed by the community not necessarily for review by a moderator.